# How to write click event for tab in angular 8

Tags: typescript, angular7, angular8

Tried to write click event for tabs but not working.How to write it? If i click the tab i want to call one function.So How to set selectedtabclick click event to tab component.If anyone know please help to find the solution.

app.component.html:

```
  <my-tabs>
  <my-tab [tabTitle]="'Tab 1'" (selectedtabclick)="test($event)">
    Tab 1 content
  </my-tab>
  <my-tab tabTitle="Tab 2" (selectedtabclick)="test($event)">
    Tab 2 content
  </my-tab>
  </my-tabs>
```

Demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tabs-example-j9ot7z?file=app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to emit an [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event) either in the Tab or Tabs component. It seems easiest to do it from the Tabs Component, plus you don't have to duplicate the markup as much. Below you'll find an example (some of your code has been omitted) and a stackblitz.

**App.component.html**

```
<my-tabs (selectedTabClick)="test($event)"> <! –– This is your Angular event. ––>
  <my-tab [tabTitle]="'Tab 1'" >
    Tab 1 content
  </my-tab>
  <my-tab tabTitle="Tab 2">
    Tab 2 content
  </my-tab>
</my-tabs>

// app.component.ts
...
selectedTabClick($event) {
  console.log($event.tab.elRef);
}
```

**Tabs.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-tabs',
  template: `
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li *ngFor="let tab of tabs" (click)="selectTab(tab)"></li>
    </ul>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `
})
export class TabsComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @Output() selectedTabClick = new EventEmitter();

  selectTab(tab: Tab){
    ...

    // emit event to fire "callback" in the app.component.html
    this.selectedTabClick.emit({tab});
  }
}
```

**Tab.component.ts**

```
export class TabComponent {

  // Inject the elRef and the constructor and assign it as a public property
  constructor(public elRef: ElementRef){
  }
}
```

Here is an (updated) stackblitz with working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tabs-example-uavrd8?file=app%2Ftabs%2Ftab.component.ts

Comment: How to get selected tab's id and element reference?  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tabs-example-bnq7es?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: You can pass the tab component as an argument to the event emitter. If you need the element ref of the tab component, you can inject the element ref into the tab component and access it as a public property on it. I've update the above example and your stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tabs-example-bnq7es?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Check my updated, answer and stackblitz. It was late when I replied and wrote the incorrect answer and didn't save the stackblitz.